# Ctree R function is not working with my for loop

Tags: r, loops, vector, ctree

I wanted to make a list for `for` loop, than I wanted to use it for `ctree` like below. but I couldn't.
I am getting, some errors like "**character is not supported**" even I change the list to `factor`

I want to change `val` variable, with the `y` list, for `for` loop.

Is there anyway to make it work?

```
y <- c("A","B","C")
x <- as.factor(y)
for(val in x) {
      ctree_model<- ctree(FTR ~ val, data = train,controls=ctree_control(minsplit=30,minbucket=10,maxdepth=10))
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula should be constructed either with `paste` or `reformulate`.  In addition, the 'ctree_model' for storing the output can be a `list` with each element of `list` stores the model that corresponds to the 'val' of x instead of overriding

```
ctree_model <- vector('list', length(x))
names(ctree_model) <- levels(x)
for(val in levels(x)) {
   ctree_model[[val]] <- ctree(reformulate(val, response = 'FTR'), 
            data = train, 
     controls = ctree_control(minsplit = 30, minbucket = 10, maxdepth  =10))
 }
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work. Where is "A", "B", "C" in here?

Comment: @sanwhere can you try now.  The step where you convert the character to factor was not needed.  So I changed it to `levels(x)`

Comment: @akun still can't see the "A", "B", "C" part in your code, how I am suppose to add A,B,C words to for loop?

Comment: @sanwhere this is your code `y <- c("A","B","C");
x <- as.factor(y);`  Can you please check by typing `x` on your console.  When you loop over the `x` or `levels(x)`, the 'val' is each element of 'x'

Comment: @akur I see now, but I got this error: "C_ExpectCovarInfluence: sum of weights is less than one"

Comment: @sanwhere that is a model error and not the code error.  It is related to your data

Comment: I change it little bit and now I have 

`
y <- c("B365H") 
x <- as.factor(y)
ctree_model <- vector('list', length(x))
names(ctree_model) <- levels(x)
for(val in levels(x)) {
  ctree_model[[val]] <- ctree(reformulate(val, response = 'FTR'), 
                              data = train, 
                              controls = ctree_control(minsplit = 30, minbucket = 10, maxdepth  =10))
  mean(ctree_predictions==test$FTR)
}
`
code like this, but now, it is not working still. "In ==.default(ctree_predictions, test$FTR) :the longer object length is not a multiple of the short obje...

Comment: @akur my data is working without loop, there is a problem with loop I guess.

Comment: @sanwhere if you have only single element, there is no need for a loop

Comment: @akur I don't, this is an example of my code. I have 10-15 variables on my list.

Comment: I don't understand what `ctree_predictions` object is`

Comment: @akur sorry, I forgot to add it into the code: `ctree_predictions <- predict(ctree_model,newdata=test,type='response')`

Comment: @sanwhere you cannot do that as `ctree_model` is a `list`.  You need `ctree_predictions <- lapply(ctree_model, function(model) predict(model, newdata = test, type = 'response'))`

Comment: @akur Actually I add the code, and tune it, thank you! it is working now.

Comment: @akur I already voted, I guess it is not visible, coz of my experience point.